# update the attachment in the document library programatically

Tags: sharepoint-server, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

i have A list and B document library . in the A list i have attachment field and once user adds an attachment it should go to the B document  library . how can i do that . and i want to do it in my event receiver .

```
using (SPSite SPSite = new SPSite(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteURL"])))
                  {
                      using (SPWeb SPWeb= SPSite.OpenWeb())
                      {

                          SPListItem ITPCItem = ITPCWeb.Lists[properties.ListId].GetItemById(properties.ListItem.ID);}}}
```

this way i am getting the SPList Item.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: This may help you: http://dishasharepointworld.blogspot.in/2012/03/movemigrate-sharepoint-list-attachments.html

Answer (score 0):

Get File from Library **A**

```
var aLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("A");
var aLibraryItem = aLibrary.GetItemById(ItemId);
var fileContentAsBytes = aLibraryItem.File.OpenBinary();
```

Now move the file in Library **B**

```
var bLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("B");
var destUrl = bLibrary.RootFolder.Url + "/" + aLibraryItem.File.Name;
SPFile destFile = bLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileContentAsBytes, true);
```

Comment: its giving me System.NullReferenceException on var fileContentAsBytes = aLibraryItem.File.OpenBinary();

Comment: May be your `aLibraryItem` is `null`. Can you update your question with code

Comment: i just used your code now , i did nothing before that to show you

Comment: oppppps ............!!! Change library name and Item Id

Comment: haha . i did that man i was saying i dint use any logic before for getting attachments so i have nothing to show .